# TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API Model Evaluation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using TensorFlow 2.x object detection API. I have trained a deep learning model from the model zoo on my dataset. I am using Google Colab. After training now I want to evaluate my model. I am using coco detection metrics. I used the following script to evaluate my model,

```
!python3 model_main_tf2.py \ 
    --model_dir = path/to/model directory \
    --pipeline_config_path = path/to/pipeline config file \
    --checkpoint_dir = path/to/checkpoint directory
```

After running the above code I get the mean average precision (mAP) and average recall (AR) for the latest checkpoint on my test set. But for academic purposes, I want to get these metrics on all the checkpoints to get a graph of how my model has improved over time. Is there a possible way to that? or is it possible to train and evaluate at the same time in TensorFlow 2 object detection API? I am a beginner in this field so kindly help me out with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional) help to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, @TFer for your help. I visited [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional) website you mentioned, but the script they have used for evaluation is the same as I have mentioned in my question, and they haven't mentioned how a model can be evaluated at all checkpoints or how training and evaluation can be done in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. So I had an idea. We can run the ***model_main_tf2.py*** you mentioned to eval the model but changing the current checkpoint (first line) to evaluate in the [checkpoint file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RqA0.png)

model_checkpoint_path: "**ckpt-1**" 
then
model_checkpoint_path: "**ckpt-2**"
then
model_checkpoint_path: "**ckpt-3**"
.
.
.

For each checkpoint you will get a ***.tfevent*** so then you open TensorBoard pointing to the directory that contains all the ***.tfevent*** and you can see how the model improves over time.

I just saved the last 3 checkpoints in my computer so I can't see the progress from the beginning (my fault) but if you have all the checkpoints try to do what I suggest.

See my [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsm6T.png) evaluating the last 3 checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an eval directory including an events.out.tfevents file under your model directory. You can run `!tensorboard --logdir=path/to/eval/directory` to access the graphs.
You can run training with the same snipped you have except without the `checkpoint_dir`and can open another terminal to run evaluation like you're currently doing.